# Getting single node from xml document c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get channel element from this document.

```
<rdf:RDF 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" 
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" 
xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:syn="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/" 
xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0">

    <channel rdf:about="http://developers.slashdot.org/">
     <title>Slashdot: Developers</title>
     <link>http://developers.slashdot.org/</link>
     ...
```

I think it's in the default namespace, which seems to be "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" so I tried like this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmsgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssDoc.NameTable);
nsmsgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/");

XmlNode root = rssDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode channel = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode("channel", nsmsgr);
```

I doesn't work. XmlNode channel stays null.

Comment: Are you sure your XPath is correct? I would think you would want to specify a "*" for the root node before specifying the child.

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, but not if he uses "*" to accept any root at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add it as Empty.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx

> The prefix to associate with the
>   namespace being added. Use
>   String.Empty to add a default
>   namespace. Note   If the
>   XmlNamespaceManager will be used for
>   resolving namespaces in an XML Path
>   Language (XPath) expression, a prefix
>   must be specified. If an XPath
>   expression does not include a prefix,
>   it is assumed that the namespace
>   Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is
>   the empty namespace. For more
>   information about XPath expressions
>   and the XmlNamespaceManager, refer to
>   the XmlNode.SelectNodes and
>   XPathExpression.SetContext methods.XPathExpression.SetContext methods.

So just add the default prefix as "default", then use "/*/default:channel".

Working code:

```
        var nsmsgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssDoc.NameTable);
        nsmsgr.AddNamespace("default", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/");

        var root = rssDoc.DocumentElement;
        var channel = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode("/*/default:channel", nsmsgr);
```

The above code works, but it's got a hardcoded URI and it uses a "cheat" to avoid dealing with the root node. Here's a cleaner, more general solution:

```
        var nsmsgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssDoc.NameTable);
        var root = rssDoc.DocumentElement;
        nsmsgr.AddNamespace("default", root.GetAttribute("xmlns"));
        nsmsgr.AddNamespace("rdf", root.GetAttribute("xmlns:rdf"));
        var channel = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode("/rdf:RDF/default:channel", nsmsgr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
XmlNode channel = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"//channel");
```

Comment: @marc_s: It's the "rdf" prefix that's optional. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
XmlElement root = rssDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlNode channel = root.SelectSingleNode("/channel");
```

That will get you the channel node, you can then reference, Attributes, Value, InnerXML, FirstChild etc to pull the data from that node.

*edit: should have been XmlElement instead of Node